# Build failed with an exception In react-native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project `:app`:

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApk'.
>   A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-maps'.
>   Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
>    You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
>   [Android SDK Build-Tools 25, Android SDK Platform 25].
>   Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
>   react-native-cli: 2.0.1
>   react-native: 0.43.3
>   react-native-maps version is 0.13.1

I actually didn't understand why this happens. When I install the api package 25 I accepted the terms and conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Under Ubuntu:

If you have Android SDK installed, and have followed this official tutorial :

> https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html

Go to the directory:

`~/Android/Sdk`

First, check that you have well the `/licenses` directory in there.

Then, copy this folder to the **android-sdk** folder as below:

```
~/Android/Sdk$ sudo cp -r licenses/ /usr/lib/android-sdk
```

This did the trick for me, Hope it helps :)